# Conditional expectation and intersection of $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, let $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{H}\subset\mathcal{F}$ sub-$\sigma$-algebras. Is it true that
$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X~|~\mathcal{G}]~|~\mathcal{H}]=\mathbb{E}[X~|~\mathcal{G}\cap\mathcal{H}]$$
holds for any random variable $X$? My attempt at a proof goes as follows:

\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[X~|~\mathcal{G}\cap\mathcal{H}]&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X~|~\mathcal{G}]~|~\mathcal{G}\cap\mathcal{H}]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X~|~\mathcal{G}]~|~\mathcal{H}]~|~\mathcal{G}\cap\mathcal{H}]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X~|~\mathcal{G}]~|~\mathcal{H}].
\end{align}
All I used is the tower property repeatedly for both $\mathcal{G}\cap\mathcal{H}\subset\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{G}\cap\mathcal{H}\subset\mathcal{H}$. In the last line I used that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X~|~\mathcal{G}]~|~\mathcal{H}]$ must be $\mathcal{G}\cap\mathcal{H}$-measurable. Is my argument correct? I haven't found anything about this on the internet.

Comment: Why must $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X~|~\mathcal{G}]~|~\mathcal{H}]$ be $\mathcal{G}\cap\mathcal{H}$-measurable?

Comment: It's not true. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220995/is-conditional-expectation-with-respect-to-two-sigma-algebra-exchangeable.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much, I should have looked over there first.